# Coordinate System independent analysis of Skeleton Data

Tags: geometry

I wasn't sure in which stack-exchange forum to post this question, but because I think this question has something to do with geometry I decided to post it here.
I have skeleton data from humans collected from three kinects fused together and I need it for further processing in Machine Learning. I have 24 labelled joints, their respective connections and their three x,y,z coordinates in a frame of reference. I only want the relation between the joints to be considered. This means that if a human is lying down oriented from North-South should be treated the same way as lying down oriented from West-East. But how can I achieve this? Even if I take only the relative vectors then the vectors will be different in these situations. I hope somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: You might want to add some more detailed information: what kind of data precisely do you have (point cloud or whatever)? To what extent is it labelled (do you know what parts belong to which joint)? What kind of joint is it (can the two parts be oriented arbitrarily relative to each other or are there some constraints)?

If you can find some way to identify 2 unique direction in each sample (for example along the length of some bone and across some feature on it) you can use these to construct a linear map that rotates your joint into a "normalized" orientation.

Comment: @SV-97 thanks for your comment. Ok, so if I for example want to normalize everything along the spine, then what I need to do is calculate all positions of the joints wrt to the spine (i.e. put the spine in the origin) and if I have two skeletons then I can rotate all the joints of the second skeleton with the linear map used to align the spines of the two skeletons right?

Comment: Yes. Let's say that the vector from the neck down along the spine of skeleton $k$ is $v_1^k$ and the one from the spine to the chest is $v_2^k$, then $v_1^k, v_2^k, v_1^k \times v_2^k$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where $\times$ denotes the cross product) with origin at the neck of the skeleton. You now fix some skeleton $K$ as a reference and map all skeletons back to that reference using the map that takes $v_1^k$ to $v_1^K$, $v_2^k$ to $v_2^K$ and $v_1^k \times v_2^k$ to $v_1^K \times v_2^K$.

Comment: In general this amounts to solving a linear system however you can make this easier by either picking orthogonal vectors to start with (so to pick $v_1, v_2$ such that they're orthogonal) or by orthogonalizing whatever two vectors $v_1, v_2$ you have.

Note that this might cause some problems depending on your data: if the reference vectors you pick are slightly different relative to one another from one skeleton to the next this might skew your whole transformation because it can't be a simple rotation in that case. You might want to look into some optimization techniques in that case.

Comment: @SV-97 thanks for the answer. That really helped.